# Creating multiple instances of a Object or property to store property values

Tags: vb.net

I do not know the exact name of what I am trying to do so bear with me... Basically I am trying to create a object(s) which will hold multiple properties.. Each one will be unique. Below is what I have so far..

```
Public Class TestingProperties

    Private m_TestId As Integer
    Public Property TestId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_TestId
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            m_TestId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_TestName As String
    Public Property TestName() As String
        Get
            Return m_TestName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_TestName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Then I the below will basically be what is contained in each object of the above as a property...

```
    Dim x As TestingProperties
    x = New TestingProperties
    x.TestName = "N/A"
    x.TestName = "Name1"
    x.TestName = "Name2"
    x.TestId = "0"
    x.TestId = "1"
    x.TestId = "2"
```

obviously this does not work because the last testId and last TestName overwrites everything contained in the object properties. Once I get this figured out the data will be provided through a SQL stored proc but the format should still be similar... Any ideas in this feat that I should have learned long ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Dim x As New List(Of TestingProperties)

    For i = 0 To 9
        Dim newx As New TestingProperties
        newx.TestId = i
        newx.TestName = "Name " & i
        x.add(newx)
    Next
```

Now you have 10 unique properties. You may access them like:

```
Console.WriteLine(x(0).TestId)
```